# Find joint probability mass function of random vector (X,Y).

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Flip a fair coin three times. Let X equal the number of heads and Y equal the number of tails.

a) Determine the joint probability mass function of the random vector (X,Y).
b) Are X and Y independent? Explain.

I'm not sure what vector has to do with joint probability mass, my teacher never introduce vector into joint probability mass and it confusing me.

For a) i know that the joint probability mass function of X and Y would just X+Y ~ Binomial (n,p). So n would be 3 and i'm guessing p will be 1/3 . Can someone let me know if i'm doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand your confusion; there's a little bit of mixed language happening here.  Let me see if I can clear it up.

The joint probability mass for $X$ and $Y$ is the function
$$
f(i, j):=P(X=i, Y=j).
$$
You can think of this as filling out a table, where the column headings are values for $X$, the row headings are values for $Y$, and the cells contain the probability of that combination.

On the other hand, you could think of this as describing the distribution of a single random variable $\vec{V}$ whose outputs are vectors $(i, j)$. In this case, the mass is a function
$$
f(\vec{v}):=P(\vec{V}=\vec{v}).
$$
In this case, you are trying to assign probabilities to each possible output vector $\vec{v}$.

These two approaches are equivalent, which probably explains the way that your instructor interspersed them.

At any rate, in your thought process you've exactly described the distribution of $X+Y$, but that isn't *quite* the same as finding the join distribution (although it is very close, and gives you lots of information).  Try filling out the table as suggested above.

Comment: hmmm if we were to solve this with table the diagonal of the table should all be 0 and the probability of like 1 head n 2 tail and etc correct?

Comment: would there be another way to find it or is the table the only way?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The table isn't a way to find it - it is what you are trying to find.

Comment: In a table with $X$ taking values 0, 1, 2, 3, and $Y$ taking values 0, 1, 2, 3, there are $4 \times 4 = 16$ potential positions to fill with probabilities. But in your problem, only 4 of those 16 probabilities can be positive.

Comment: @BruceET i mean if were making a 4 by 4 matrix it would be 16 position to fill but almost all of them are 0 beside the positive correlation  right? because you flipped it 3times so the sum must be 3 . Example 3 head 0 tail = 1/8         0 head and 3 tail = 1/8   and 1 head 2 tail = 3/8    and 2 head and 1 tail = 3/8 so there actually only 4 probability

Comment: @darkflames363 Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @darkflames363 If you don't like the table representation, you could certainly define a piecewise function; something like $$f(i, j):=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{8}\binom{3}{i} & \text{if }i+j=3\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you Nick! i understand it a lot better now!

Comment: Maybe on the right track. Can you evaluate $P(X = 1)$ and $P(X = 1, Y = 2).$

Comment: and to prove it independent or not i just find p(x,y) = or != p(x) p(y)

Comment: @BruceET i'm not sure i follow what you mean by $P(X=1) and P(X=1,Y =2)$ ?

Comment: I mean find $P(X=1)$, then find $P(X=1,Y=2)$, then compare them. From what you say above, I'm not absolutely sure you have the right answers.

Comment: hmmm i'm not sure cause i use basic stats to calculates 1 head 2 tails which should be 3/8  even if u were to try a tree diagram there only 3 possibility

Comment: I'm not sure what @BruceET is getting at, other than that my answer hasn't addressed your question of independence.  However, having the table makes it very easy to establish that these variables are not independent.  One way to do so is to notice that $P(X=1, Y=2)\neq P(X=1)\cdot P(Y=2)$.  The left quantity comes from the table; the right quantities from marginalizing the table.

Comment: thx nick i got that a few hours ago i did the same thing as u :) i got 3/ 8 != to 9 / 64